# jquery CDN が 403 forbidden

Tags: jquery

昨日のよるぐらいからあちこちのサイトで表示や挙動がおかしく

最初は原因がまったくわからず色々調べていくうちに
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js
このアドレスが403を返してきます

公式のCDNなのですが何かアクセス規制にひっかかるような条件があったりするんでしょうか
悪いサイトをふんでこのアドレスに負荷をかけるようなことをしてしまったんでしょうか

Comment: 該当のアドレスで正常にアクセスできているのですが今も403でしょうか？

Answer (score 6, accepted):

公式CDN (code.jquery.com) で発生している不具合のようです。

参考：
[jQueryのCDN（code.jquery.com）が403エラーで読み込まれない不具合が発生中](https://blog.ikunaga.net/entry/code-jquery-com-is-not-loaded/)

> この不具合は、code.jquery.com以外のCDNを利用する or 自分のサーバ内にjQueryのファイルを置き、それを読み込ませることで解消します。
>
> (中略)
>
> 今回の不具合は、日本（東京ノード）＋IPv6＋HTTPSという限られた環境で発生しているようです。
> (現在、CDNプロバイダーへ問い合わせ中とのこと。)

Comment: サーバー側の問題だったのですね…　何かやらかしたのかと思って泣きそうでした